# How to use a google cloud VM instance as a server, provided I already have a .jar executable?

Tags: java, spring, server, jar, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to set up an application for a university project. It is a maven/tomcat Spring Boot application (a website) which I have coded at my local machine using STS.

The application works fine on my local machine, meaning I've compiled it into a jar file, ran it and I can see it from localhost. Links, cookies and everything work as intended. Now, I want to run it in a google cloud VM instance with tomcat preinstalled and a static IP address, but I am quite unsure on how to do it.

I tried using scp to transfer the jar file (along with all resources and classes) to my VM instance and I ran it from there. But when I try to kill all tomcat8 processes, run my file, I am still prompted to the classic "It works!" page, not my pages.

I am very new to these things, so be aware that I may be oversimplifying the process. Should I plug the files into some specific folder? Any insight as to how I should proceed is more than welcome. Thank you all for your time. ~Mike

Comment: There are a lot of online resources to learn how to do this. YouTube has some good videos. Google has tutorials. Qwiklabs has labs that walk you thru each step. We do not need to duplicate this on Stackoverflow. Invest the time to learn. Setting up a VM, installing Java, managing firewalls, security, etc. requires you to know how. When you have a programming problem come back and post a question. Read this so you know how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run `.jar` file directly, then follow the below steps:

```
1. scp app.jar <IP>:.
2. cp /home/ubuntu/app.jar /opt/tomcat/webapps/
3. cd /opt/tomcat/bin/ // Assuming tomcat is properly installed with users configured.
4. ./catalina.sh start // Start the tomcat
```

The above setup should be sufficient to deploy the application. If you monitor the tomcat startup logs, you will get registered URL for which the application was registered.

The tomcat deployment is fine, but there is a better way: Using docker (For first time setup users, steps might be bit confusing. Will try to explain all the steps but bit of google is required, if any step is not working as expected.)

Following solution involves following steps:

```
1. Install docker on the server.
2. SpringBoot application configuration for containerization on the host machine.
3. GCP configuration on the host machine for pushing the built image to private container repository.
4. Configuration of the server for GCP for pulling the image from private container repository and finally starting the application.
```

First:
Install the docker on to the server using this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Second: Setup/Configure the spring boot application for docker deployment.

1. Install spotify docker plugin for maven, so that, docker image is build during maven build process and we will also add required docker configuration for maven here.

a. At the top of your `pom.xml`, after the `<parent>` tag, add the following meta-information about your project

```
    <groupId>com.companyName</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectArtifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Project Name</name>
```

b. Under `<build><plugins>` section, add the following code:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
        <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>build</goal>
                    <!-- <goal>push</goal> -->
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <repository>companyName/${project.artifactId}</repository>
            <tag>${project.version}</tag>
            <noCache>true</noCache>
            <buildArgs>
                <JAR_FILE>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</JAR_FILE>
            </buildArgs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

In the above step, we have added docker plugin to maven build process and also added meta-information about the project, so that, the `.jar` is built with the said name and version.

2. In the root of the project, create `Dockerfile` and add the following content:

   ```
   # Use java 8 on bare linux as our base image
   FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

   # Accepting argument from mvn plugin
   ARG JAR_FILE

   # Set ENV mode
   #ENV STAGE=default
   ENV DOCKER=true

   # Renaming Jar File
   COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

   # Starting the application
   CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app.jar"]
   # For actual prod applications, profiles wrt application.properties are used, but for college project, its ok*(Ignoring for first time configuration)
   # CMD ["java", "-Dspring.profiles.active=${STAGE}", "-Dserver.port=6262", "-jar", "/app.jar"]

   # Assuming the application port to be 6262. Replace with the appropriate port.
   EXPOSE 6262
   ```

Now the required configuration at SpringBoot side is done. To get the application for deployment, we need to first build the `docker image`. This can be done by:

```
a. cd to root of the project.
b. docker build -t companyname/projectname .
```

The above step will build the image. Built images can be viewed by `docker images`

3. Now we need to configure from GCP side: (Will not be descriptive. Lot of good articles can found, please google.)

   a. [Configure GCP container registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/quickstart) and also `gcloud-cli` in your laptop (It is bit tricky for first time users, but a bit of research is better than typing the straight forward answer)
4. Once `gcloud-cli` is configured, push the image to the registry.

   a. docker images
   b. copy the built image's image id.
   c. docker tag  /: (Please go through the documentation of GCP for example)
   d. docker push /:

Now we have pushed the built image to private docker repository.

4. ssh to server: (This step can be done in multiple ways and for real use -cases, CICD pipeline tool is ideally used.) Here we will follow a simple method.

   ```
   a. Configure gcloud-cli with new IAM user in the server.
   b. Login to gcloud repository
   c. docker pull <asia.gcr.io/gcp-project-id>/<project>:<tag>
   d. docker run -p <hostport>:<applicationport(6262 here)> --name container_name -d <asia.gcr.io/gcp-project-id>/<project>:<tag>
   ```

The above step should start the docker container and SpringBoot application should be running. From here, one can configure reverse proxy if required, or update the firewall settings, so that traffic can be reached to the said port.

I understand, it's a tad bit difficult and confusing, but I suggest, a lot of research will help you. Once familiar with `docker`, `gcloud-cli`, it wont be confusing any more. Let me know, if any step in detail is required.